# lodash npm distribution in browser

Tags: npm, karma-runner, bower, lodash

I'm using lodash in my tests, Not using webpack or browserify (don't need to).

I found that the default npm build differs from what's in bower. I could of course use bower version, but I'm curious if I can use npm's instead (it's already there for Gulp).

For bower I could just add this line to karma.conf:

```
bower_components/lodash/lodash.js
```

but in default npm distro there's no lodash.js. Of course I can always build whatever version I want using lodash cli. But maybe there's even easier way, say maybe I need to add more than just one file from `node_modules/lodash`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `node_modules/lodash/index.js`

Comment: I can swear I did try that, but for some reason it seem not working. Just tried it again and it worked.

Comment: { pattern: './node_modules/lodash/index.js', watched: false} isn't working for me. Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
  at node_modules/lodash/index.js:1